# To make an action based on the link location by jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, find, hyperlink

**How can you retrieve the value of the rel attribute of a given link and pass it to the handler?**

I have a list of links such that

**Link list**

```
<div id='one_answer'>Answer1
    <a href="$" class="delete_answer" rel='Answer1'>delete</a>
</div>
<div id='one_answer'>Answer2
    <a href="$" class="delete_answer" rel='Answer2'>delete</a>
</div> 
<div id='one_answer'>Answer3
    <a href="$" class="delete_answer" rel='Answer3'>delete</a>
</div>
```

These links are generated by the following code.
The following value of the rel does not seem to be passed to the handler.

**Links generated by PHP**

```
    echo ($answer . "<a href='#'"                                                                                                                  
        . "class='delete_answer'"
        . " rel='" . $body . "'"         // I identify the answer
                                         // by the body of the answer
                                         // in the database
        . ">delete</a>"
    );
```

The user clicks the second link.
The rel attribute should pass the answer to the handler.
jQuery should perform the following action based on the POST -data.

**jQuery**

```
jQuery('a.delete_answer').live('click', function(){
    jQuery.post('/codes/handlers/delete_an_answer.php', 
        { delete_answer: jQuery(this).attr('rel') },    
        function(){
            $("#one_answer").removeClass("yellow");
        })
});
```

**The file delete_an_answer.php**

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=masi user=masi password=123");
// remove the answer
$result = pg_query_params ( $dbconn,                                                                                                                                                                           
    'DELETE FROM answers 
    WHERE answer = $1',
    array ($_POST['answer'] )    // Problem here, because
                                 // $_POST['answer'] is empty when it gets here
                                 // so no answer is deleted
);
```

I fetch answers from Postgres and put at the same time the value of the rel attribute to be $body.

Comment: You should probably explain what the problem is... "problem here" doesn't say much. The code you've written should "work", in so far as it will retrieve the value of the `rel` attribute and pass it to your handler... If you just want the index of the link that was clicked, i'm not sure what the rest of the question is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see several problems with this code:

1. You have more than one `<div id='one_answer'>`. IDs should be unique, so `$("#one_answer").removeClass("yellow");` will always select *the first div*, not all divs.
2. delete_an_answer.php - In the php you're looking for `$_POST['answer']`, but the ajax has `{question_id: jQuery(this).attr('rel')}`.
3. The links in your sample don't have a `rel`, and `href='$'`, which is weird. Also `<div id='one_answer>` is broken, should be another single quote. I assume these are copy-paste problems.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by (2). - **Do you mean that I should change the code to `{question_id: $(#one_answer).attr('rel')}`?**

Comment: I opened a new thread based on your point #1 here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351063/using-post-in-jquery about the reference to a POST variable in jQuery.

Comment: #1 has nothing to do with POST - you have many object with the same ID - this creates bugs, and invalid. #2: You're sending the rel data from javascript with the key `question_id`, but on php you  try to read the key `answer`. try $_POST['question_id']

Answer (score 1):

Ok, well... To answer your first question, you can get the index of the element that was clicked within the array of elements matching a given selector using jQuery's [`index()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/index) method:

```
$('a.delete_answer').live('click', function()
{
  var index = $("a.delete_answer").index(this);
  // index will be 0 for the first matching link, 
  // 1 for the second, and so on. Do what you will with this...
  ...
});
```

As for the rest of your question, I really have no idea what it is you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! - I clarified my question.

Comment: The current problem is that I do not know what $_POST['body'] contains. If I knew that, then I could know where the problem is.

Comment: I opened this thread which aims to solve the other problem first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350779/to-see-the-content-post-data-trasferred-by-jquery