# Using POST in jQuery

Tags: jquery, post

**How can you use POST in this command?**

```
var answer = $('#answer').val();
jQuery('div.answer_' + answer + ' a.delete_answer')
               .live('click', function(){
```

This should match this

```
 div.answer_answerExample a.delete_answer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are completely misusing the **post** function. What I believe you meant to do is this.

```
$('div.answer_' + $('#answer').val() + 'a.delete_answer')
```

On a side note JavaScript is case-sensitive and calling **$.POST** would also throw object not found error.

See the jQuery Docs for further reference.

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post

Answer (score 2):

$.POST is a function not a variable that you can concatenate with strings. I don't understand what are you doing but you can't do it in this way. If yuo explain me better what you're tryng to do i can give you my help.

Answer (score 2):

you need to fetch the result from `post` into some variable then you can use it in your code as follows (from [jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post) page):

```
var anaswer;
$.post("YOUR_PAGE", ,
  function(data){
    alert(data.answer); 
    answer = data.answer;
  }, "json");
```